# Http streaming, how it works?

Tags: python, http, networking, stream

Let's assume I request a large object from a server, and I want to write it to the disk while I don't want to use a lot of memory (the object should not be fully loaded into memory, for example my object is about 5GB but my memory limitation is 100MB).
I write here a code in python for example

```
response = requests.get('https://example.com/verylargefile.txt', stream=True)
chunk_size = 1024*1024*15 # =15MB chunk for example
with open(f'some_file_name.txt', 'wb') as file:
    for block in response.iter_content(chunk_size):
       file.write(block)
```

1. In this code, for every 15M we get, we write them to the disk, but, in reality, will the file data pile up in memory? Like more data would come than the amount I will be able to write to the disk in a given time?
2. How does the streaming works? (I am familiar with HTTP streaming) does after each 15MB I handle I ask for the next 15MB from the server? (I'm sure it's not like that, but how it's like?)